# SQL server Pandas connection

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyodbc

```
conn_str = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=DESKTOP-NGVLFO7;''Database=AdventureWorks2019;''Trusted_Connection=yes;')
input_query = '''select
     year(t1.OrderDate) as 'año',
     month(t1.OrderDate) as 'mes',
     sum(t1.TotalDue) as 'ventas'
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as t1
    group by year(t1.OrderDate), month(t1.OrderDate)
    order by year(t1.OrderDate), month(t1.OrderDate)'''

ventas = pd.read_sql(input_query, conn_str)
```

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I tried but it won't let me connect.

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.